# does Mma provide exact critical values of Mann Whitney U (small samples)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, core-language

Does Mma provide exact critical values for the Mann Whitney U test, along the lines of [haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.8.0.4/docs/Statistics-Test-NonParametric.html)?

Or just as good, for given two small samples, can I easily ask `MannWhitneyTest` to efficiently compute an exact p-value, along the lines of or [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/exactRankTests/versions/0.8-31/topics/wilcox.exact)?

Comment: Have you seen [`MannWhitneyTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MannWhitneyTest.html), especially the Properties listed under Details and Options?

Comment: @LouisB 
Yes, sorry: misspelled. Is there a way to use it for an efficient exact test?